# How can I fully install a Midlet Suite App onto BlackBerry "over the air" rather than using the javaloader?p

Tags: deployment, blackberry, ota

i currently have a fully working app suite compiled to .jad and .cod (ported from j2me) that i am able to use on a BlackBerry only if i install it using the javaloader util. however, i need to deploy the app OTA, and when i download and install the app from a .jad the app is nowhere to be found on the device.

does anyone have any pointers? this is my first stack overflow post, so do let me know if i should give you more details to better help you understand the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take at look at RIM [documentation for OTA deployment](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB17084)

There maybe more up to date documentation, but RIM website is the place to find this kind of information.

This may be more up to date : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link, @Michael B.  I wonder if the problem lies with my app being a midlet suite (actually comprised of 5 separate apps).  I suppose I should try to generate a .jad that explicitly lists the midlets contained in the main module.  Of course, I will "RTFM" on my own, but, if anyone has any expertise to share, any boost would be appreciated!

Comment: @Harlo Holmes, usually by installing RIM plugin for eclipse, creating a BlackBerry project and building it, will create all the files you need to deploy OTA. Even if it's a Midlet App.

Comment: Thank you!  At work, they gave me a bunch of "deliverables" that were generated by the BB-ant server, and were somehow incomplete.  I did as you suggested-- cracked open my windows machine and built it from source using the Eclipse plugin and voila.